# How to store data in Akka Actor Object fields?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

How can I use a mutable Map in an Actor object to store values depending on the messages?
My code

```
object TestActor {
   final case class Command()
   private val mmap: mutable.Map[Int,Map[Int,Int]] = mutable.Map[Int,Map[Int,Int]]()
   
   def apply(): Behavior[Command] = Behaviors.receive {
       case (context, Command()) => 
            mmap += (1 -> (2 -> 3)) 
            context.log.info(nmap)
   }
}
```

This causes problems since the `mmap` is static as it is a field in a scala object. So when multiple threads add some values to the map, it would result in strange values. Since I still need to use typed akka actors, is there a way to have a field in an object (or in some other way) to make it possible for me to still use objects to represent the actors using `akka.typed` and still have fields that are not shared among the `TestActor` actors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Akka Typed's functional API (which this example uses), the typical way to do this would be along these lines:

```scala
object TestActor {
  final case class Command()

  def apply(): Behavior[Command] =
    fromMap(mutable.Map.empty)

  private def fromMap(mmap: mutable.Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]]): Behavior[Command] =
    Behaviors.receive {
      case (context, Command()) =>
        mmap += (1 -> Map(2 -> 3))
        context.log.info(mmap)
        Behaviors.same
    }
}
```

Here, the `object` is basically serving as just a module and the fields of that object are better thought of as globals.

Note that there is also an object-oriented API for defining typed actors, which in Scala would be:

```scala
object TestActor {
  final case class Command()

  def apply(): Behavior[TestActor.Command] =
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
      new TestActor(context)
    }
}

class TestActor(context: ActorContext[TestActor.Command]) extends AbstractBehavior[TestActor.Command](context) {
  val mmap: mutable.Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]] = mutable.Map.empty

  def onMessage(msg: TestActor.Command): Behavior[TestActor.Command] = {
    mmap += (1 -> Map(2, 3))
    context.log.info(mmap)
    this
  }
}
```

It's worth noting that in Akka, it's generally better to have `var`s of immutable data (i.e. mutable containers holding immutable values) than `val`s of mutable data (i.e. immutable containers holding mutable values), as that can expose a channel for something outside the actor (including another actor) to "pull the rug out from under" an actor.

In the functional API, this would typically take a form like:

```scala
object TestActor {
  final case class Command()

  def apply(): Behavior[Command] =
    fromMap(Map.empty)

  private def fromMap(map: Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]]): Behavior[Command] =
    Behaviors.receive {
      case (context, Command()) =>
        val nextMap = map + (1 -> Map(2 -> 3))
        context.log.info(nextMap)
        withMap(nextMap)
    }
}
```

And in the OO Scala API:

```scala
// TestActor companion object is as before

class TestActor(context: ActorContext[TestActor.Command]) extends AbstractBehavior[TestActor.Command](context) {
  var map: Map[Int, Map[Int, Int]] = Map.empty

  def onMessage(msg: TestActor.Command): Behavior[TestActor.Command] = {
    map = map + (1 -> Map(2 -> 3))
    context.log.info(map)
    this
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Levi, I appreciate the effort of your response. I still have two questions:
1) I don't see where `withMap` is which is used in `apply()` method. Shouldn't be `fromMap`?  


2) Can you send the links of the sources where you found this info about the API? it was a pain for me to get something that is between OO and FP.  


Other than those question, I want to thank you for providing the information as it prevented a great amount of refactoring otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I started with `withMap` and then decided `fromMap` was a better name :)

Comment: For a discussion of the functional and OO APIs, the best links to start from are: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html#functional-style, https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html#object-oriented-style, and https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/style-guide.html